# Activity history Stack is not getting clear

Tags: android, back-stack

I have 4  Activity classes `e.g A, B, C and D` here i am going to B from A and then C and in the menu of this(C) activity i have given a link for Activity A so when i am selecting that menu i am going to A and again from A i am going to B from here i am going to D and come back to B and then going to C.
So overall scenario is `A->C->A->B->D->B->C`
now the problem is while pressing back button it goes like this

```
C->B->D->B->A->C->A exit
```

but i want to use like this if users in activity A its directly close the app no need to go back to B and then C but if its in B then no need to go back in C Activity.So for the C and D i am using `android:noHistory="true"` and its working fine but i can't use this thing for B. because while coming back from D to B , i can't skip B Activity and directly jump to A.
So now stack is like this:

```
C->B->A->A exit
```

Following that i have tried is:

```
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Thanks for considering.

Answer (score -1):

Where you use Intent it stores the previous activity in the stack so use finish method to clear the stack like example

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this,b.class);
startActivity();
finish();
```

Answer (score -1):

this code will help you

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.Class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```